# How to minimize an IFolder in the ICustomPerspectiveLayout

Tags: java, eclipse, layout, view, perspective

I have created a new folder in my perspective by calling

```
IFolderLayout folderStat = IPageLayout.createFolder(...);
```

I added multiple views in these folder by calling

```
folderStat.addView(SomeView.ID);
```

How can i minimize the created folder, so that the folder is minimized by default, when the perspective is shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The org.eclipse.ui.actions.ActioFatory has some logic for MAXIMIZE/MINIMIZE active pages.

```
IViewPart part = pWindow.getActivePage().findView(pViewName);
pWindow.getActivePage().activate(part);
ActionFactory.IWorkbenchAction minimizeAction = ActionFactory.MINIMIZE.create(pWindow);
if (minimizeAction.isEnabled()) {
   minimizeAction.run();
}
```

May be i can use this for minimizing the folder, in which all my views are shown.